# How can I apply classNames in react to change the background color of one of the child div in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, class-names

I have 3 children `divs` wrapped in one parent `div` as shown :

[image]

On click of each child `div`, I want its background-color to be changed to red. but if there is already one `div` with background-color red and some other `div` is clicked then its background color should be changed to white. There will be only one `div` with background color red. I am newbie to react. I read about [classNames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) and `states` in React but can't find out how can I do this.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I advice you to start with something really simple like just get a click to log some information when pressing a div. Then go on to get the div to change color when clicking the div. Then create a component from that code that will expose the onClick event and that it takes a color as a prop. Then combine that in a new component that has a state that holds the current "selected" div. It is important when you are new to this to try it out yourself, that is the only way to really learn. If it is hard, make it easier by dividing it up in smaller parts. GLHF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want like so

```js
var Сards = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      cards: [
       { name: 'сard 1', isActive: false },
        { name: 'сard 2', isActive: false },
        { name: 'сard 3', isActive: false }
      ]
    };
  },
  
  handleClick: function (index) {
    const cards = this.state.cards.map((card, i) => {
      card.isActive = i === index ? true : false;
      return card;
    })
    
    this.setState({ cards })
  },
  
  render: function() {
    const cards = this.state.cards.map((card, index) => {
      return <div 
       key={ index } 
        className={ 
          card.isActive 
            ? 'cards__card cards__card_active' 
            : 'cards__card'
        }
        onClick={ () => this.handleClick(index) }
      >
        { card.name }
      </div>
    });
    
    return <div className="cards">
      { cards }
    </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Сards />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.cards {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.cards__card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

  .cards__card_active {
    background: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try jQueryToggle.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("p").toggleClass("main");
        });
    });
```

```
    Toggle class "main" for p elements

    This is a paragraph.
    This is another paragraph.
    Note: Click the button more than once to see the toggle effect.
```